# Maintaining session across the same browser

Tags: session-state

We have the requirement to maintain the session in the multiple browser.

Example : If the user logs-in to the site in chrome browser
and after login if the user opens the URL in the another chrome browser, the session need to be maintained.

Do we have the OOB feature in Sitecore or do we need to write some custom code.

Note: We are **not using** the Sitecore Experience DB

Comment: The session, or the login?    Also - are you deliberately trying to make your systems less secure, or is this an Intranet situation where everyone is authenticated by the AD?

Comment: Hi Mark, This will be  public site. We are using the virtual user to create the users. Currently we have the login component in the home page. once the user provided the user name and the password to login into the site, he lands to the product list page. At the same time if the user opens the home page url in the another chrome browser, the product listing page should open

Comment: If you have your login/sessions set up correctly then this should be the default behaviour. Opening a new tab shares the same session information.

Comment: All tabs/windows of Chrome will use the same session to the same URL. If you switch to incognito, then of course no.

Comment: Hi Chris/Jammy, This is working. But the scenario is, if the user already logged in and open the same login page in the new tab, the page has to be redirected to different page.